# Compare lm models from subset of data or find inflection point to remove lag time

Tags: r, lm

I am running lots of linear models on data from different experiments where we want to exclude a lag time from the start of the experiment.  This lag time may vary between runs and is very obvious in the example plot below.  Is there a robust way to automatically exclude the lag time, in my example below it would be where x < 1

I thought the way to do it would be to produce linear models and gradually remove points from the start of the data and compare models but I don't know the best way to compare models from subsetted data

```
df <- data.frame (x1 =  c(0.7,1.7,2.8,3.7,4.9,6.0,6.7,7.7,8.7,9.7,10.7,12.0,13.1),
             y1 = c(22.7,50.7,103.2,143.4,175.2,216.8,234.1,246.6,256.0,266.2,276.0,287.6,295.5))

plot(1/df$x1, log(df$y1), type = "l")

summary(lm(log(y1) ~ I(1/x1), data = df))
summary(lm(log(y1) ~ I(1/x1), data = df[df$x1 > 1,]))
summary(lm(log(y1) ~ I(1/x1), data = df[df$x1 > 2,]))
```

Comment: How to you recognise the lag time? What characteristic defines when it occurs in the data?

Answer (score 0):

i. generate list of 14 data.frame, where v = 0 to maximum integer value of df$x1

```
library(dplyr)
all.dat <- lapply(max(df$x1) %>% seq(from =0, to=.), function(v) df[df$x1 > v,])
```

ii. generate list of lm models using 14 data.frames

```
lm.form <- as.formula("log(y1) ~ I(1/x1)")
all.lm <- lapply(all.dat, function(x)lm(lm.form, data=x))
```

iii. view summary of all 14 lm models

```
lapply(all.lm, summary)

sapply(all.lm, function(x)summary(x)$r.sq) #extract r.sq value for all models

[1] 0.9074019 0.9960153 0.9957543 0.9903552 0.9783031 0.9937000 0.9899247 0.9915223 0.9982270 0.9997441 0.9998207 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```